# How to solve this probability question using complements?

Tags: probability

Please help to with this probability question. I can solve it normally but I do not know how to approach it using complements.

Qn:
It is known that in a large population, 10% of the population has blood group AB, Three people are randomly chosen one at a time from this population. 
Find the probability that at least one person has blood group AB.

P(at least one person has blood group AB)
= 1 - P(all three people has non-AB blood group)
= 1 - 9/10 ** 3

But the answer I got differs from the answer I got for my normal way of approaching this problem which is consider case by case. (1 AB blood group, 2 AB blood group and all 3 AB blood group)

Please help me! TYVM!

Comment: $1-(\frac{9}{10})^3$ should be correct, how did you calculate it case by case?

Comment: Oh damn, I realized my mistake. So by complement, it is correct. When I calculated the probability case by case, I forgot the order of choosing the people matters too

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. question solved

Comment: The order actually does not matter.. Since this is binomial distributed you can use the formula for $k$ of $n$ people have the feature AB blood group $= \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. the $\binom{n}{k}$ means in how many ways you can choose $k$ people out of $n$. My english is not the best so maybe you already meant that.